# Get the class-name of a Java inner class' outer class instance

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
abstract class Base {
...
  public class Inner {
    private final String ownerClassName;
    public Inner() {
    ...
    }
  }
  public static class Super1 extends Base{
  ...
  }
  public static class Super2 extends Base{
  ...
  }
}
```

I would like `Inner.Inner()` to set `ownerClassName` to the type of the enclosing class instance, e.g. "Super1" or "Super2".
How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Base.this.getClass().getName()
```

Comment: In my test this doesn't _quite_ work. I get the fully qualified class name i.e. instead of "Super2" I get "package.Base$Super2". Should it be `getSimpleName()`?

Comment: @John: Probably.  Are those classes also nested?

Comment: Actually yes, in my specific case. Updated code accordingly though I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: @John: It makes a difference in terms of the name you'll get.

Answer (score 2):

First remove final from ownerClassName, make it private and provide only get method if you want.

Then follow the code:

```
Inner() {
   ownerClassName = Base.this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: why should it not be final, it should be set in ctor and never changed?